# Closure of Intersection

Tags: general-topology

Given a topological space $\Omega$.

By minimality it holds:
$$\overline{A\cap B}\subseteq\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$$

Especially one has equality for:
$$A=\overline{A}:\quad\overline{A\cap B}=A\cap\overline{B}$$
How to check this quickly?

Comment: Do you want to prove equality for general case ?

Comment: I think it is not true: take $A=[0,1]$, $B=(1,2)$, then $A=\overline A$, $\overline{A\cap B}=\emptyset$ and $A\cap \overline {B}=\{1\}$.

Comment: @user59363: Great thanks!

Comment: So let me change it to subspaces...

Comment: @Freeze_S, Please clarify what do you want to be discussed, nest time !

Comment: @FardadPouran: It wasn't clear to me that it may fail. I think I'll leave it the way it is now. However your answer doesn't match to any of my concerns. If you're not sure what the question is then let me help clarify; it is my duty to do so.

Comment: Aha ! Ok . I thought you wanted to prove equality for the first line you wrote !

Comment: And yes I was hoping to prove equality. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if $A= [0,1]$ and $B=(1,2),$ then $A \cap B = \emptyset$ so $\overline{A \cap B} = \emptyset,$ but $A \cap \overline{B}= [0,1] \cap [1,2]=\{1\}.$ So you don't have the equality.